Compiling multiple python files and json files into a single executable Using Nuitka
I was writing some python codes. Created 3 py files named main.py, port.py and launcher.py. The launcher.py is just a simple code to just launch the the other two-:
launcher.py-
import subprocess
import time

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'port.py'])

time.sleep(1) 

# Start the second process
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'])

# Wait for process to finish execution
proc2.wait()
proc1.terminate()


Tried compiling them into single executable using nuitka but they just won't work. I want a single executable exe file that I can share with other. I tried these nuitka commands-
nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json launcher.py


nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json --include-module=main --include-module=port launcher.py

Using these two commands the launcher.exe is being generated in the dist folder but when opening it says main.py and port.py not found. Then I tried this---
nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json --include-data-file=main.py=main.py --include-data-file=port.py=port.py launcher.py

Using this the port.py and main.py were present in the dist folder and running properly but there are loads of other files. Lots of dll and py files.
I wanted something simple like a single executable with few dll files if necessary.
How do I achieve this? I am using nuitka instead of pyinstaller as I wanted greater code obfuscation.
(Sorry for such a long rant)
nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json launcher.py


nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json --include-module=main --include-module=port launcher.py

Using these two commands the launcher.exe is being generated in the dist folder but when opening it says main.py and port.py not found. Then I tried this---
nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --include-data-file=config.json=config.json --include-data-file=main.py=main.py --include-data-file=port.py=port.py launcher.py

Using this the port.py and main.py were present in the dist folder and running properly but there are loads of other files. Lots of dll and py files.
I wanted something simple like a single executable with few dll files if necessary.

Use regular imports instead of subprocesses.

Will it affect the performance in any way? Like i need the the port.py to start first then the main.py otherwise it won't work.

Regular imports should be faster
